# How to use VSCode product icon for command in extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add a button to the 'editor/title' section which runs my command. With my current configuration, my command name appears when unfolding the menu by clicking the 3 buttons. What I want is to have an icon presented (like for the split editor button), which runs my command.

From the documentation I found that it should be possible to supply an svg file for the icon, but I prefer to use an icon from the [product icons](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels#icon-listing). This way the icon can change along with the theme.

Is that even possible, or am I just configuring it incorrectly?

This is the config I have so far:

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "my-extension.my-command"
            "title": "My Command",
            "icon": "preview" // <-- this refers to the icon from 'product icons'
        }
    ],
    "menus": {
        "editor/title": [
            {
                "when": "resourceExtname == .xyz",
                "command": "my-extension.my-command"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should works:

```
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "my-extension.my-command"
            "title": "My Command",
            "icon": "$(preview)" // <-- the syntax for using a 'product icon' is $(iconIdentifier)
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a note for anyone stumbling upon this, I also needed to add `"group": "navigation"` to the menu secyion

Comment: Also note that this doesn't work if you try and specify separate light and dark mode icons, only if you set `"icon"` directly to `"$(iconIdentifier)"`